# AWS CLI V2 Issue with Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am running a local docker container which installs the v2 AWS CLI using CURL, unzip, .aws/install. 
I am able to get output from aws2 --version, but when I try to run any command such as `aws2 iam get-user`, it returns the following:

```
local variable 'process' referenced before assignment
```

There is a new line if that helps in debugging. Cannot figure out why this would ever happen...

Comment: What is the version of python?

Comment: docker has python 3.7, but aws cli v2 comes with it's own python env

Comment: I would consider reporting issues, as requested, at https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues.

Comment: good suggestion: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4758